# Закрытие подписки disposable в Rxjava в Android

Tags: android, rxjava2

Недавно на код ревью услышал от сеньора, что типа подписку Rxjava закрывать необязательно во вью модели, так как модель умрёт и подписка вместе с ней, а до тех пор она все равно ещё нужна или там один единственный ивент. Т.е. он утверждает, что можно dispose не делать, и что он вообще в студии вырубил ворнинги, с этим саязанные.
Честно говоря, меня это немного покоробило, но он старший на проекте, а я новичок, и я не стал много спорить на эту тему.
Так ли это?

Comment: Ну так возьмите, проверьте, запустите бесконечный Observable во ViewModel, который что-то выводит в лог каждую секнду, например. Повесьте лог на коллбек onCleared, а потом выйдите с этого экрана и посмотрите, умрёт ли подписка или нет. А потом можете делать различные выводы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если viewmodel подписан на какой нибудь долго живущий объект, он не будет уничтожен сборщиком мусора пока не отменить подписку. Поэтому надо отписаться в методе `onCleared()`.
Можете прочитать про эту тему в этой [статье](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) в параграфе **Leaking ViewModels**